# Check if NSURL is Local File

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is a pretty simple question- how can I check if a NSURL is linking to a local file?

I know, RTFM, but I checked the documentation and I don't seem to see any methods related to this.

The only methods I *did* find were `-isFileReferenceURL` and `-isFileURL`, but I think these only check if the URL directly links to a file.

*Note:* I'm making an iPhone app, so by "local file" I mean a .html file stored in the project's resources.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `-isFileURL` will check if your URL uses the `file:` scheme. It doesn't check whether it's referencing an actual file.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure exactly what that meant.

Comment: @Goles how come is it iOS8+ if the answer is from 2010?

I just checked the header and there is no annotation about the availability at all, so I assume it has been there for ages.

Answer (score 7):

There is [`-isFileReferenceURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/isFileReferenceURL) as of iOS 5 that checks if the url is an file reference. Before 5.0, it did nothing according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/isFileReferenceURL)..

> Available in iOS 5.0 and later. (Symbol is present in iOS 4, but performs no operation.)

I hope this helps the new-comers...