# How can I tell if a string is an URL or a local path?

Tags: swift, nsurl

I'm given a string.  It will either be a local path to a file that exists or a fully qualified remote https url ending in a file component.

If it is a local path I want to use `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: String)`.
If it is an URL, I want to use `NSURL(string: String)`.

What is the simplest / most reliable way to decide which to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057588/check-if-nsurl-is-local-file

Comment: That alleged duplicate is how to check an NSURL, not a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A local file path string will always start with `/` assuming it is a full path (which it should be).

A remote https URL will start with `https://`

Simply check which prefix the string has.

Comment: What about `NSString isAbsolutePath`?  I can't figure out how to call that from swift though.

Comment: `isAbsolutePath` is really just going to see if the string starts with `/`.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks.