# Check if NSString is Local File

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, filepath

This question is NOT duplicated with [Check if NSURL is Local File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057588/1677041).

I have two kinds of string path point to local file path and remote file path which may have an HTTP/HTTPS/FTP scheme.

```
NSString *path = ... ; // like "https://img.server.com/foo.jpeg" or "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxx/data/Containers/Data/Application/xxxx/Documents/file.txt"

NSURL url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSURL url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

I checked the `scheme`, `fileURL`, `isFileReferenceURL` properties, none of them could help me identify whether the NSString path is a local file path or remote file URL.

Please help!

Comment: Is your question asking how to determine whether you should create an `NSURL` from an `NSString` using either `URLWithString:` or `fileURLWithPath:` depending on the value of the string?

Comment: Yes, `URLWithString:` is used for general remote file url, `fileURLWithPath:` is used for the local file path, I think. I need to know whether the source path is a local file path or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying all kinds of URL example, I think the NSURL class may not the final way for this to check the local file path. Now I use the following function.

```
BOOL IsLocalFilePath(NSString *path)
{
    NSString *fullpath = path.stringByExpandingTildeInPath;
    return [fullpath hasPrefix:@"/"] || [fullpath hasPrefix:@"file:/"];
}
```

It covers the local file paths like `/path/to/foo`, `file:///path/to/foo`, `~/path/to/foo`, `../path/to/foo`.

It works great for [Unix-like path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) so far, punch me there are some exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check the prefix of the file path?

```
BOOL       bIsFileURL = [path hasPrefix: @"/"];
```

Or, could it be a relative path?
In that case, you could check for the http://, https:// or ftp:// prefixes in a remote path:

```
NSString   *schemeRegex = @"(?i)^(https?|ftp)://.*$";
BOOL       bIsRemoteURL;

bIsRemoteURL = [path rangeOfString:schemeRegex
                           options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound;
```

Comment: Yes, I want a more general string path function to validate the local file path.    The regular expression doesn't help here as the url scheme could be [any types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

Comment: Then use this. You can't have a : in a file path, but any url scheme will have one.

bIsRemoteURL = [path rangeOfString:@":" options:NSLiteralSearch].location != NSNotFound;

On the other hand, if the remote URL won't have a scheme, then you can't distinguish between a file or remote URL. You could check to see if a local file with the name exists, but that's problematic because, without the scheme, a file could also exist with the remote url path.